# Sorting Lists containing numbers

Tags: python, function, sorting, statistics

I have a series of lists like this that include scores.The first number following the name is student status. 1=Freshman 2=Sophomore 3=Jr.4=Sr

```
Ablao 3 74 96 72 88 71 80 83 77 90 88 95 71 76 94 80 74 98 77 
Anderson 3 76 92 98 95 92 76 93 97 85 76 85 93 82 88 75 84 92 77 
Aspinwall 1 86 74 78 97 86 94 73 95 74 91 75 94 83 99 83 78 88 96 
Bacon 4 72 95 81 80 89 88 100 87 87 81 79 77 75 83 87 96 72 95
```

I need to create a function that will compute various statistics such as high, low mean of lab avg., program avg, etc based on the year of the student. I already have functions created for averages. I am just having trouble sorting the data by year of the student.

So far I have,

```
 All_Years=[]

 Freshman=[]

 Sophomores=[]

 Juniors=[]

 Seniors=[]

def make_lists_of_status():
if (student_status==1):
    Freshman.append(student_scores)


elif (student_status==2):
    Sophomores.append(student_scores)


elif (student_status==3):
    Juniors.append(student_scores)



elif (student_status==4):
    Seniors.append(student_scores)



elif(student_status==1 or 2 or 3 or 4):
    All_Years.append(student_scores)





 def statistics_func():
     user_stat_choice='x'
     print("This option is used for viewing statistics sorted by the     year of the student")
     print("Please select one of the following options:")
     print("(a) for All Years, (b) for Freshman, (c) for Sophomores,   (d) for Juniors, (e) for Seniors")
     user_stat_choice=print(input("Enter your choice here:"))

    if(user_stat_choice=='a'):

    print ("Hi/Low/Mean of all weighted scores   is:",max(All_Years),min(All_Years),(sum(All_Years)/len(All_Years)))

    print ("Hi/Low/Mean of all lab averages is:")

    print ("Hi/Low/Mean of all program averages is:")
```

Here is a sample of how the output should be 
    You have selected Statistics

```
This option is for viewing statistics sorted by the year of student.
Please select one of the following options: 
a for ALL YEARS
b for FRESHMAN
c for SOPHMORES
d for JUNIORS
e for SENIORS

Enter your choice here: a
For All Students:
High/Low/Mean of all Weighted Scores:  89.9 / 81.6 / 85.41883333333335
High/Low/Mean of all Lab Averages:  89.6 / 79.6 / 85.28333333333332
High/Low/Mean of all Program Averages:  98.33333333333333 /     71.66666666666667 / 85.90555555555554

Back to the Main Menu....
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "sorting data by the year of students"? It would be nice if you could add sample input and output.

Comment: Just added a sample @VedangMehta

Comment: Also, your `All_Years` list would be null as it will never be possible to get to the last `elif` statement

Answer (score 0):

```
Ablao 3 74 96 72 88 71 80 83 77 90 88 95 71 76 94 80 74 98 77 
Anderson 3 76 92 98 95 92 76 93 97 85 76 85 93 82 88 75 84 92 77 
Aspinwall 1 86 74 78 97 86 94 73 95 74 91 75 94 83 99 83 78 88 96 
Bacon 4 72 95 81 80 89 88 100 87 87 81 79 77 75 83 87 96 72 95
```

To read this from a file:

```
f = open("path to file")
data = [a.strip('\n') for a in f.readlines()]
```

Now to sort it an example:

```
for i in data:
    n = i.split(" ")
    if n[1] == "1":
        for x in n[2:]:
            Freshman.append(int(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend creating a student class

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name, status, *grades):
        self.name = name
        self.status = status
        self.grades = grades

   @property
   def student_year(self):
       return ('Freshman','Sophomore','Junior','Senior')[self.status-1]
```

This could easily be populated from a CSV file and stored in a list, `All_Years`. You could then get you list by

```
freshman = [student for student in All_Years if student.student_year = 'Freshman']
```

You could also skip the `student_year` things, but it does make the later coding easier to read.

Consolidated grades could be done using the built-in module `itertools` by

```
freshman_grades = list(itertools.chain(student.grades for student in freshman))
```